# Scala: Expression of type Unit doesn't conform to type List[List[Boolean]]

Tags: scala, list, boolean

I'm trying to produce a function that returns a List that contains Lists of Booleans in Scala. So far, the function looks like this:

```
def listListBool(n: Int): List[List[Boolean]] = {
   val empty: List[List[Boolean]] = null
   if (n == 0) {empty}
   else if (n ==1) {val bools = List(List(true, false))
}
```

The 'else if' part of the statement flags up with the error: "Expression of type Unit doesn't conform to type List[List[Boolean]]" even though I have specified that the program needs to return a List of Lists of Booleans. I have also tried the following syntax:

```
else if (n == 1) {val bools: List[List[Boolean]] = List(List(true, false)
```

But the same error is still produced. Am I missing something really obvious here? I feel like have been staring at this for hours and I still can't quite grasp what I'm getting wrong.

Please keep in mind that I'm quite new to Scala and I'm not entirely familiar with all the ins and outs of the language and its syntax.

EDIT: I replied to some comments on this stating that an 'else' was due to be added following fixing this problem. Looking through your comments, I tried adding one anyway and that was what fixed it. I still don't quite understand how that changes the return type from being 'Any' to the correct type but it works none the less.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several problems with this code. First you have a structure like

```
if ...
else if ...
```

This is wrong because it would yield `Unit` if neither the first nor the second condition were met. What you want is:

```
if ...
else if ... //optional
else ....
```

Secondly an assignment always yields `Unit` and `val bools: List[List[Boolean]] = List(List(true, false)` is an assignment. Just write  `List(List(true, false)`.

Third if you want to return the empty List you have to write:

```
List.empty
```

or better

```
Nil
```

I am surprised that you don't get an error for returning `null`.

Comment: There is an 'else' to follow after the 'else if' but I wanted to get the error fixed before moving forward. Have taken your advice for the returning of empty lists. Makes much more sense! I'm not sure why I wasn't using it before. Thanks for the advice!

Comment: @haffla, He is not returning null. He is returning a valid type which has value null.

Comment: @Manish Mishra, His advice produced a cleaner style and ultimately fixed the problem. It's really what I should have been doing rather than creating a whole new variable just to assign it a null value. haffla, Thanks again, problem fixed!

Answer (score 1):

`val bools: List[List[Boolean]] = List(List(true, false)` is an assignment, which is of type `Unit` you want `List(List(true, false)` without the assignment.

Comment: That alone won't fix the problem.

Comment: Have tried this and it comes back with the same error except with the type 'Any' rather than 'Unit'.

Answer (score 0):

You can just write a simpler version instead of function doing the same.

```
def listListBool(n:Int) = if(n==0) Nil else List(List(true,false))
```

If you are using a Typesafe language, using null should completely be avoided.